# stress test video streaming

Tags: video, streaming, load-testing

is there a way to stress test video streaming? 
Basically simulating a high number of people simultaneously streaming a video?

This is an amazon 'cloud' service that will be enabled for my site.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you would like to stress?

Some examples we like to use (that are specific to Webmasters, as opposed to the kind of solutions you would find on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), [where the question is also posted](https://serverfault.com/questions/264149/stress-test-video-streaming)) are:

- stability under truly random [RED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_early_detection) conditions, consider everyone else's Internet is broken and dropping packets
- concurrent users behind different proxies (especially [where the admin is trying to cache YouTube](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube) and other video streaming servers), [JeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_enough_operating_system) instances under [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org) are your friend here
- simultaneous [HTTP Content-Range requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (the more invalid ones mixed in the better)
- testing the system under a simulated [TCP Global Synchronisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_global_synchronization) event
- using [Slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris)
- deliberately reordering packets (especially with multicast)